# Error 14 The type or namespace name 'Document' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
Document document = new Document();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

                document.Open();
                document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
            }

            document.Close();

            stream.Flush(); //Always catches me out
            stream.Position = 0; //Not sure if this is required
            return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

i got the same error for pdf writer and Paragraph

Comment: And *have* you got the appropriate `using` directive and assembly reference?

Comment: no i don't knw which one should i use kindly tell me

Comment: @ArslanSunny: looks like you are using iTextSharp. Please refer the dll in your project and use the relevant iTextSharp namespaces. CTRL+. will help you with that. also read this. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp

Answer (score 2):

i am having the  same problem then i find the answer

First of all be quiet sure that iTextSharp.dll is added to reference and

then at the starting of the main form. Add this

```
using iTextSharp.text; 

using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

iTextSharp.text is responsible for Document Object